# How many traversals need to be known to construct a BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, inorder, postorder, preorder

I am very confused by a number of articles at different sites regarding constructing a `Binary Search Tree` from any one traversal (`pre`,`post` or `in-order`), or a combination of any two of them. For example, at [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/657) page, it says that given the `pre`,`post` or `level` order traversal, along with the `in-order` traversal, one can construct the `BST`. But [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/25203) and [there](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/25268), they show us to construct a `BST` from `pre-order` alone. Also, [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/24867) they show us how to construct the `BST` from given `pre` and `post-order` traversals. In some other site, I found a solution for constructing a `BST` from the `post-order` traversal only.

Now I know that given the `inorder` and `pre-order` traversals, it is possible to uniquely form a `BST`. As regards the first link I provided, although they say that we can't construct the `BST` from `pre-order` and `post-order`, can't I just sort the `post-order` array to get its `inorder` traversal, and then use that and the `pre-order` array to form the `BST`? Will that be same as the solution in the 4th link, or different? And given `pre-order` only, I can sort that to get the `in-order`, then use that and the `pre-order` to get the `BST`. Again, does that have to be different from the solution at links 2 and 3?

Specifically, what is sufficient to uniquely generate the `BST`? If uniquement is not required, then I can simply sort it to get the `in-order` traversal, and build one of the N possible `BST`s from it recursively.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To construct a BST you need only one (not in-order) traversal.

In general, to build a binary tree you are going to need two traversals, in order and pre-order for example. However, for the special case of BST - the in-order traversal is always the sorted array containing the elements, so you can always reconstruct it and use an algorithm to reconstruct a generic tree from pre-order and in-order traversals.

So, the information that the tree is a BST, along with the elements in it (even unordered) are equivalent to an in-order traversal.

**Bonus:** why is one traversal not enough for a general tree, (without the information it is a BST)?

**Answer**: Let's assume we have `n` distinct elements. There are `n!` possible lists to these `n` elements, however - the possible number of trees is much larger (2 * n! possible trees for the n elements are all decayed trees, such that `node.right = null` in every node, thus the tree is actually a list to the right. There are `n!` such trees, and another n! trees where always `node.left = null` ) Thus, from pigeon hole principle - there is at least one list that generates 2 trees, thus we cannot reconstruct the tree from a single traversal.
(QED)

Comment: So the solutions at 2nd and 3rd links generate the only possible `BST`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I did not follow the code there - but if it is correct then yes. There is only one BST for each pre-order traversal.

Comment: Then see the article at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/6633. They construct a `BST` from `pre` and `in-order` traversals. But considering that the tree can be constructed from the `pre-order` alone, don't you think that the binary search needed in this code to find the position makes it less efficient? Won't it be more efficient to not use the `inorder` at all, and simply use the `pre-order` to construct the tree? However, will the two solutions necessarily yield the same tree?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: The in-order + pre-order traversal solution is constructing a *tree*, it does NOT have to be a *BST*. BST is a specific case where the in-order is implicitly known and can be used. Assuming the two solutions are correct - getting the pre order and in order, and invoking the last algorithm will yield the same tree as invoking the first algorothm (pre-order alone).

Comment: By the way, can you give me an idea or link to a resource on how to construct the `BST` from the `post-order` array only?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of one (It really does not thing exist, it just mean I never researched about it)/

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this a bit more: *Thus, from pigeon hole principle - there is at least one list that generates 2 trees, thus we cannot reconstruct the tree from a single traversal*?  And how does pigeon hole principle apply here?

Comment: @Nawaz pigeonholes: permutations. Each permutation is a pigeonhole. There are n! of those. pigeons: all distinct trees with n unique elements (same `n`). There are `X > n!` such trees. Let `f:trees->permutations` be any mapping function. Since `|trees| > |permutations|`, there are some `x!=y` such that `f(x) = f(y)` (pigeonhole principle). That means, given only `f(x)`, you cannot construct uniquely the tree led to `f(x)`, because it could be either `x` or `y`. I hope that's clear, let me know if this explanation is missing any critical details.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for an awesome explanation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the values for the nodes of the BST are given then only one traversal is enough because the rest of the data is provided by the values of the nodes. But if the values are unknown then, as per my understanding, constructing a unique BST from a single traversal is not possible. However, I am open to suggestions.